# Page refresh event 'window:beforeunload' does not work on Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to do a redirect when page refresh, i use

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
    unloadHandler(event) {
        window.location.href = "myUrl"
    }
```

but redirection does not occur

If i use

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
    unloadHandler(event) {
        window.location.href = "myUrl"
        event.returnValue = null;
        return null;
    }
```

A warning will appear and after clicking cancel redirection occurs, but I do not need pop-ups

Comment: Please don't redirect users that try to leave your website.

Comment: Have you tried using Router from @angular/router

Comment: they don’t try to leave, they refresh the page, and I redirect to the page of my site

Comment: my application does not support router, this option is not possible

Comment: beforeunload doesn't know about refreshing or leaving. It redirects anyway.